# How i can disable alembic logging at runtime?

Tags: python, logging, alembic

I need to disable alembic migrations logging, while executing migrations in unit tests, .

I can't just remove `alembic` logger it from `alembic.ini`: i need this output while performing migrations myself.

Following did not work for me:
`logging.getLogger('alembic').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

How i can disable it at runtime?

Comment: Check if you have right name of logger by printing:  `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict`

Comment: If you are able to use it (and I highly recommend py.test), https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-capturelog might help you.

Comment: Are these really / only alembic logging Infos or SAWarnings or similar from sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to edit the alembic.ini file and change the logging setting for this particular log. You can read about it in the [relevant section of the Alembic tutorial](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file). By default, this section should be in your configuration file:

```
[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic
```

I set mine to `WARN` instead, and these logs went away.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're invoking Alembic from within your unit tests by calling out to the `alembic` command, which is a separate process and does not inherit your logging configuration.

Instead, you should invoke Alembic programmatically:

```
import logging
import alembic.config
import alembic.command

logging.getLogger('alembic').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

alembic_cfg = alembic.config.Config('alembic.ini')
alembic.command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, 'head')
```

See the documentation for more info about the [Alembic API](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to change it in the `alembic.ini` file but instead in the `env.py` file. There will be a line in there that looks like

```
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
```

This will be what sets up the logging with the alembic.ini config file. After this line you can do whatever you want to the alembic logger by doing

```
logging.getLogger('alembic')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on other answers, that's what worked for me:

```py
import alembic.config
import alembic.command

alembic_cfg = alembic.config.Config('alembic.ini')
alembic_cfg.set_section_option("logger_alembic", "level", "ERROR")
alembic.command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, 'head')
```

Instead of importing logging, we can just replace config section value that contains info about log level.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way if you want to keep alembic's logging configuration and remove it when running programmatically is to change alembic's `env.py`:

```py
import logging

...


if not logging.getLogger("myappname").handlers:
    assert config.config_file_name
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
```

This assumes that you added a handler to your application's root logger (at `myappname`). It ensures that alembic does not try to reconfigure your logging if it's already configured (e.g. with a lib such as structlog).